# VSCode : run a pre-deploy script with Live Preview extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the VSCode [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server) extension for local testing of a static website.

Can I have a node js pre-deploy script run before the preview refreshes?

Currently, I'm using `nodemon` to watch for file changes and then run the script, but it would be more convenient if there were a built-in way to do this.